# Meta query for comparing two dates

Tags: plugins, wp-query, meta-query

I want to list all users who registered in between the $start_date and $end_date.I have written a metaquery,but it returns empty.Please help.

```
$start_date        =  2014-08-16 09:28:17
$end_date          =  2015-08-16 09:28:17
$current_user_id   =  get_current_user_id();
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'user_registered',
            'value' => $start_date,
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'user_registered',
            'value' => $end_date,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'key'  => 'referral_id',
            'value' => 'current_user_id',
            'compare'=> '=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    ),

);
$users = get_users($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

start and end date is following the date format. But you are using NUMERIC type casting in meta query. You need to use DATE type like

```
array(
            'key' => 'user_registered',
            'value' => $start_date,
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'user_registered',
            'value' => $end_date,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
```

Hope that this will help you.

Ahh...there have another problem. You are saving the data in `$current_user_id` but you are not using this variable in third array. Try this once

```
array(
            'key'  => 'referral_id',
            'value' => $current_user_id,
            'compare'=> '=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
```

Full Code:

```
$args = array(
   'meta_query' => array(
                         array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'user_registered',
                                    'value' => $start_date,
                                    'compare' => '>',
                                    'type' => 'DATE'
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'user_registered',
                                    'value' => $end_date,
                                    'compare' => '<=',
                                    'type' => 'DATE'
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key'  => 'referral_id',
                                    'value' => $current_user_id,
                                    'compare'=> '=',
                                    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                                )
                        )
                  )
);
$users = get_users($args);
```

Try my full code now.

Comment: NO still it returns an empty array. :(

Comment: Ok. I am editing my answer and giving the full code

Comment: Bro.It working but it returns all the users not getting filtered.

Comment: Ok. this is great news change the variables like this `$start_date        =  '2014-08-16 09:28:17';
$end_date          =  '2015-08-16 09:28:17';`

Comment: no change bro :(

Comment: The field `user_registered` is from table `wp_users` and `referral_id`  is from `wp_usermeta`.Does it matter ?

Comment: Ahh...then meta query will not work. Meta key & value will work for custom field. You need to write a SQL query and use $wpdb->get_results() function. this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is now to use  [`WP_Date_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_date_query/). See the `date_query` field in [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) is described as:

> An array that is handled through to the WP_Date_Query object. Date queries are allowed for the user_registered field.

You can generate the `date_query` array here: https://generatewp.com/wp_date_query/

#### Example

```php
$date_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'before'        => '2019-05-31',
        'after'         => '2019-01-01',
        'inclusive'     => true,
    ),
);
$users = get_users([
   'date_query' => $date_query
]);
```